# Expect script exiting too fast when trying to load data from DB

Tags: postgresql, csv, expect, psql

I have an expect script that loads data from a heroku postgres database into a local .csv file. I need to use expect due to a need for automation and entering a password. So far my script looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <username> -W <db name> -t -A -F "," -f sql.sql -o output.csv
expect "Password for user <db name>: "
send "<password>\r"
sleep 10
```

The `sql.sql` is a sql query, for example `select * from my_table`.
Notice that I need to add a sleep at the end of my expect script to allow data to be written to .csv file otherwise nothing gets written. However, if the data I am trying to load is too big then I will have to keep adjusting the sleep time every single time. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid adjusting sleep for different queries, Just add global timeout in expect script.

```
set timeout -1
```

so your script would be something like this :-

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1
spawn psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <username> -W <db name> -t -A -F "," -f sql.sql -o output.csv
expect "Password for user <db name>: "
send "<password>\r"
#sleep 10
```

Hope it helps.